# MS Access - Calculate end date based on the next start date

Tags: date, ms-access

I have a fact table where each key has a status (active, inactive,deleted,...) running from some start date.

```
key-status-start
01-active-01/01/2019
01-inactive-03/01/2019
02-inactive-01/01/2019
02-active-10/01/2019
02-inactive-15/01/2019
02-deleted-17/01/2019
```

Now, I need to add another column with an End Date. Is there a way for it to be calculated automatically based on the start date of the next status for that same key?

The desired result would look like this:

```
01-active-01/01/2019-02/01/2019
01-inactive-03/01/2019-n/a
02-inactive-01/01/2019-09/01/2019
02-active-10/01/2019-14/01/2019
02-inactive-15/01/2019-16/01/2019
02-deleted-17/01/2019-n/a
```

Comment: By default, no. Though, you could make an UPDATE query to accomplish it. Is your date form in DD/MM/YYYY?

Comment: you can do it using macro - when new record is inserted, update the latest record with the same key

Comment: @vol7ron yes, it is using this format

Comment: Also something to consider: usually an active date ends the same day as an inactive date. Many times they’re the same timestamp, or off by microseconds. Not sure about your data, but may be something to consider

Comment: @June7 this is a similar question, but ultimately different because I do not operate across key boundary (key 1 and key 2 have no relation)

Comment: @June7 I pieced together the way to approach it, however it is still a different question. None of the other questions are limit to a single key (this I resolved) but I am still missing the "n/a" result where there is no following result. Instead I have empty value, which is not what I need.

Comment: Yes, the query returns Null when there is no value. Why is this an issue? The "n/a" can provided by textbox expression in report. Can wrap the entire subquery in Nz() function and all values returned will be a string.

Comment: It seems my version of Access is demanding a registration key that I can’t find (it’s approaching a decade old). If I can find it And register, I can help, but until then *goodluck* :D

Comment: Can you edit the question with your current solution?